# EF Core nested entities handling

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have .NET Core app with EF Core.

I need to get list of Thread objects, but I also need one property from nested table, it's `dbo.Container.Description`

I do:

```
var threads = this.context.Threads
                .Include(x => x.ThreadsPosts)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Post)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.CreatedByUser)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.UserProfile)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Container);
```

and then I go through loop of Threads:

```
var description = thread.ThreadsPosts.Last().Post.CreatedByUser.UserProfile.Container.Description;
```

but as I understood I got data from all columns of all nested tables?

So is there any performance issues?

Maybe there is a way to reduce count of columns?

How to properly write this construction?

Comment: Depends very much on what the end result should look like.

Comment: @GertArnold any example how to do it the best way? I need all columns from dbo.Thread and dbo.Container.Description column.